# Fiat Palio 1.2 injector failure

Tags: gasoline, fiat, palio

I have a fiat palio 1.2 2003 model,

Recently the fuel injector warning light came on the dashboard and its went off some times. The vehicle runs smooth with some lag in the power especially when I try to overtake any other vehicle.

There is no big difference in the millage when the warning light is on, but when it is in the off state the millage goes down very badly but no difference in the power.

So I have checked the every injector using engine stethoscope and came to know that the injector in the second cylinder is not making any knocking sound. I have checked the resistance of the same using a multimeter and no resistance indicating on it. And its clear that the injector is faulty.

My Question is, if the injector is completely faulty, why the warning light turn on & off and its resulting the millage difference?.

Comment: Interesting. I have never heard about a fuel injector warning light even though I have had several fuel injected cars with model years from 1989 to 2016. I have however heard about the check engine light.

Comment: @juhist its a warning light inside the dashboard 

http://i67.tinypic.com/5zfwap.jpg